# How to do ZFS incremental backup to IBM TSM

Tags: backup, zfs

I am going to set up a new zpool. I plan to use nested datasets to store individual files. For example I could have the following datasets:

```
tank
tank/homes/user1
tank/homes/user2
...
tank/shares/pub
tank/shares/misc
...
```

`tank` is the zpool itself, it contains no files, instead, all files are stored in the datasets like `tank/homes/user` and so on.
Now I want to set up a proper backup for this. The problem is that the zpool will be large (100T) and therefore, the incremental backup will take a long time, therefore the files can change during the backup and the backup agent will then retry the backup, which slows it further down etc.
So I planned to make a snapshot, like `zfs snap tank@backup`, then use the snapshot to perform the backup, and then destroy the snapshot afterwards.
However, this does not work, as the snapshot `tank@backup` will not contain the sub-datasets like `tank/shares` or `tank/shares/pub`. However, with `zfs snap -r tank@backup` I get recursive snapshots, but I cannot use these, as it will be messy for the restore of the backup.

Unfortunately, I cannot use `zfs send` and `zfs receive` for the backup, as I use IBM Tivoli / Spectrum Protect for the backup, i.e. `dsmc`, which, to my knowledge, needs files to backup, and I believe it won't work with `zfs send`.

So I believe, I will probably end up with just backing up `/tank/*`, e.g. something like `dsmc incremental /tank/* -subdir=yes`, which ignores all ZFS features and will backup datasets like ordinary folders and so on.

Is there probably a better method?

Comment: One might be able to backup each dataset on its own, with their own snapshots; to avoid changing files. NetApps can backup ndmp-dumps in TSM^wSpectrum Protect. That avoids seeking for changed files. Maybe one can generate ndmp-dumps (with the help of zfs-snapshots) to send them into Spectrum Scale.

Comment: I forgot: ndmp backup does not backup single files but dumps of a filesystem; so it is more suited for desaster recovery. one would need organize file based backup/restore via snapshots.